# How can make a relation between 2 class in one program?(android)

Tags: java, android, image, class

I must write a program with android which can find other ssid's and show them. I desinged it with 2 xml pages. I create an imagebutton in page2 and want to make a relation between imagebutton and searching method. It means i want to click on imagebutton and seaching method begin it's work and search ssid's and show them...
My problem is, I download my search method and because of that i can not recognize which method i must call on my setonclick method that i write for an imagebutton in second page? I try to create another class seperately for search method and call it from the second class of page2.
but i dont know how can i make a relation between these 2 calss(i mean the second and third class). Or i must write the method of searching and on click of my imagebutton in one class?
Thanks for your suggestion.this is the code that i was copy:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class wifiScan extends Activity {

    private class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
      public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
        Date tempDate=new Date();
        String info=testNumber+" "+(tempDate.getTime()-testDate.
          getTime()) +" "+results.size();
        Log.i("wifiScan", info);    
        wifiText.setText(info);
        testNumber++;
        testDate=new Date();
        wifi.startScan();

        }
    }
    private TextView wifiText;
    private WifiManager wifi;
    private WifiReceiver receiver;
    private Date testDate;
    private static int testNumber=0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        testNumber=0;

        wifiText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiText);
        receiver=new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilte
           (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifi =(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){

            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

          }
        startScan();


    }
    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        finish();
    }
    public void startScan(){
        testDate=new Date();
        wifi.startScan();
    }
}
```

Comment: not clear. try to clarify your precise issue.

Comment: don't understand your issu

Comment: My advice.  You will never be successful copying and pasting code.  You should learn the basics of Java first, then Android.

Comment: Can you be plz more clear with your question?

Comment: I want to use this block of code in my program... I have an imagebutton that should be a start key for this code. I want to use onclick method but dont realise which method must be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
you_image_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, wifiScan.class);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this realy work? I dont see non of my method names in your code (method names i mentioned upper part)?

Comment: Where i should use this code? in this block of code in upper part or in another class i create?

Comment: @MelisaDaisy Dyna didn't gave you a code you can copy and paste straight away. You should find what is *your_image_button* in your application and attach that code to it.

Comment: You mean i must use this code in class i create my imegebutton?

Comment: yes Melisa. Try that and let me know. I recommend you learning some android basics like Activities, Intents, ..

Comment: I do it but it shown a message: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<WifiScan>) is undefined      now what should i do?

Comment: instead of :
`Intent i = new Intent(this, wifiScan.class);`
put:
`Intent i = new Intent(NameOfYourActivity.this, wifiScan.class);`

Comment: May i have a little study abouy activity ... and ask you again? maybe tommorow?

Comment: here is a link Melisa:  [tutorial android activities](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html)   
you need to post more information about your code and errors (log_cat output)

Comment: Thank's a lot. Do you know how can i download the pages of link of website you recommanded?